# Trying to get an object to bounce once on the ground - then when it falls again go through the ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Here's the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class groundCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool hasTouchedGround = false;

    public CircleCollider2D cC;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "ball")
        {
            hasTouchedGround = true;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (hasTouchedGround == true)
        {
            cC.isTrigger = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have two gameObjects. One is a ball, named "ball",  with the tag "ball" and the other is a square that has been stretched on the X axis into a large rectangle and named "ground" with no tag. The ball has a rigidbody set to dynamic (there will be lots of balls and the point of the game is to click the balls as they fall to gain points) and a CircleCollider2D, and the gravity scale has been set to 0.5 (Although I had the same issue when using a normal gravity scale of 1).

I want the ball to be able to rebound off of the ground (which has a BoxCollider2D and a Physics Material 2D with a bounciness of 1) and be able to be clicked even if you missed it the first time, but I only want this to happen once, so I want the CricleCollider2D to become a trigger after it touches the ground once, allowing it to still be clicked but letting the ball fall through the ground next time. However, with this script, the collision isn't being detected.

When the ball hits the ground and bounces off, the boolean "hasTouchedGround" doesn't become true. What could be causing this? I double checked all my references and they are all good, the CircleCollider2D (cC) referenced in the script is set to the CircleCollider2D on the ball. I don't think it matters, but the ground object is off-screen slightly so the ball will go off screen for a split second then come back on screen for you to click again.

Comment: Have you tried adding a [physics material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html), and setting the bounciness to something higher?

Comment: @ken I already have a physics material on the ground and setting the bounciness any higher makes it bounce off the top of the screen. unless you mean add a physics material to the ball in which case how would that help?

Comment: I asked that question before I read the whole question. I didn't understand your problem. I will try to answer it now.

Comment: @ken ahhh okay thanks! Im interested to see what you have to say because this really confuses me lol. I'm a bit of a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in unity2d, you need to make sure that everything you do is not 3d. Since you are detecting 2d collisions, you need to make sure that the right methods are being called.

When testing this out, I tried putting a print statement in the `OnCollisionEnter`, and got nothing even when the ball hit it. This is because `OnCollisionEnter` is detecting 3d collisions, and `OnCollisionEnter2D` detects 2d collisions. If you use the 2d version, you also have to have 2d arguments. In this case, we use `Collision2D` instead of `Collision`.

Here is what you should do:

```cs
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "ball")
        {
            collision.collider.isTrigger = true;
        }
    }
```

I changed your code a little big, but yours should work, if it doesn't, change yours to mine.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes sense, i don't know why i didn't think of it!

Comment: Don't use `GetComponent` .. we already **know** the collider: [`Collision2D.collider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-collider.html)

Comment: Also what is this good for `bounced = true; if (bounced == true)` (besides the typo) ? Of course this condition is always true since you set it right before. There is no use of having that flag at all ;)

Comment: collision.gameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().isTrigger is the same as just collision.isTrigger
You only need to do it like this if you have 2 different colliders which is... well, fundamentally wrong if allowed. Always try to aim for low end machines and that means, avoid the GetComponent whenever possible.

Comment: @Rhach actually `GetComponent` uses hashes (in later versions) and is not thaaaat expensive (anymore). Anyway in this case here it is just unnecessary both performance and readability wise ^^ btw it is `collision.collider.isTrigger` not `collision.isTrigger` ;)

Comment: @derHugo I think I fixed all of the bugs.

Comment: @ken nope you didn't read all comments ;) it is `collision.collider.isTrigger = true;` and the `bounced`/`bounces` is still a typo but the entire field + check is completely unnecessary since you always set it to `true` right before checking its value ^^

Comment: @derHugo Okay, here is a [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-isTrigger.html) that tells me I can just use Collider2D.isTrigger. Am I understanding you wrong? I also removed the whole bounces thing, so when they bounce it sets it to a trigger to fall through the floor the next time.

Comment: @ken yes but `Collision2D` != `Collider2D` ;)